# How to make this method generic?

Tags: c#, generics

How can I make this function generic?
At the moment this method retrieves a list of type item. What I want to do is to call on this method, with a generic datatype, like Item, Category or Group. All of these has the same property name.

How can I do this?

In logic / service layer with reference to the Data Layer:

```
public class TaskHandler : ITaskHandler
{
     public async Task<List<newDataType>> Handler(List<Item>() items)
    {
        var newList = new List<newDataType>(); 
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            newList.Add(new Item
            {
                ID = item.ID,
                Name = item.Status,
                Retrieved = DateTime,
            });
        } 
        return newList ;
    }
}
```

In dataaccess layer

Datatype1.cs

```
public class Datatype1
{
    public int ID{ get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string Group{ get; set; }
}
```

Datatype2.cs

```
public class Datatype2
{
    public int ID{ get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string Group{ get; set; }
}
```

Datatype3.cs

```
public class Datatype3
{
    public int ID{ get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string Group{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What's this -> `List<Item>() items`?

Comment: `Task<List<T>> Handler(List<Item>() items) where T: MyInterface`?

Comment: Create a generic interface with the shared properties. Let all the datatypes implement this interface and allow the method to accept a list of this interface

Comment: you can use T and Interface if they all have common properties , or you can use reflection and get all the items from the class

Comment: you don´t do anything with `newList`, but return `messages`?

Comment: There is no important where you want define the interface, If I were you I defined that `Interface` in a common library, which can be added as a reference where I want.

Answer (score 3):

As all of your types have the same property, you should have a common base-class or interface for them. Then you can easily add a generic constraint to your method:

```
public async Task<List<T>> Handler<T>(List<Item> items) where T: MyInterface, new()
{
    var newList= new List<T>();
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        newList.Add(new T
        {
            ID = item.ID,
            Name = item.Status,
            Retrieved = DateTime,
        });
    }

    // ...
}
```

with

```
interface MyInterface
{
    // the common properties
}
```

and

```
class Item : MyInterface { ...}
class Category : MyInterface { ...}
class Group : MyInterface { ...}
```

Apart from this I can´t see why your method is `async` at all, as there´s nothing that can be awaited here.

Comment: and if those classes don't share properties>?

Comment: @styx "All of these has the same property name."

Comment: @styx if they don't share properties, then should they have a common generic method?

Comment: Hello, the last part with class item : MYInterface, where should it be? :)

Comment: Where you delcare your classes?

Comment: `Constraints are not allowed on non-generic declarations` where is the `Handler<T>(...)` ?

Comment: The classes are in the models project, Category, Items and Group has their own files. @HimBromBeere

Comment: @HimBromBeere, Thanks, DownVote reverted.

Comment: @Bladeluster I can´t see why it should matter matter, in which file they are stored. Does that mean you can´t let your classes implement an interface? That would have been a really important detail to your question.

Comment: Could you provide an example of how a fully class datatype should look like?

Comment: @Bladeluster I don´t know much about your types, so I can´t provide you any example for them. If you don´ßt know how to implement an interface - that´s a completely different question which should definitly not go into this existing one.

Comment: I know how to implement an interface, I just don't understand "how you would map up these in a interface". Should it be in the Data access layer or in the Logic / service layer? My models are in the DataAccessLayer.

Comment: @Bladeluster It´s where you declare those classes. For me that sounds like data-access. If your class is `partial` it *may* go to the latter as well.

Comment: @HimBromBeere

I've updated the thread. Is that to more help?
Where should I put the common interface?

Comment: Updated the class.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is async although there is no calls to async. It returns a "message" although there is no reference to any "message" variable. The code is pretty unreadable so its hard to know exactly what you want.

But you need to wrap the method in a generic class. Maybe something like this is what you want.

```
public class Foo<T> where T : new()
{
    public IEnumerable<T> Handler(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        var list = new List<T>();

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            list.Add(new T
            {
                ID = item.ID,
                Name = item.Status,
                Retrieved = DateTime.Now,
            });
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your method inside a class which can accept T type (where T : class, new()). and add your method which accept the T - type parameter and return T-type of object.

return message can be newList.

```
    public class Item
    {
      public int ID { get; set; }
      public string Status { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IRepositoryClass
    {
      int ID { get; set; }
      string Name { get; set; }
      DateTime Retrieved { get; set; }
    }

    public class YourRepositoryClass<T> where T : IRepositoryClass, new()
    { 
     public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> Handler(List<Item> items)
     { 
       var newList= new List<T>();
       foreach (var item in items)
        {
         newList.Add(new T
         {
            ID= item.ID,
            Name= item.Status,
            Retrieved= DateTime,
         });
      }
   return newList; } 
}
```

Comment: The classes are in the models project, Category, Items and Group has their own files.

Answer (score 0):

If all those `classes` have the same method named `Handler` do something like you define a parameter T on the interface level, and your methods can use this parameter in their prototype, so any class that will be implementing this interface will naturally implement the parameter T within its own methods.

```
interface IBaseInterface<T>
{ 
   Task<List<T>> Handler(List<T> items);
    // the common properties
}
```

and then do:

```
public class A : IBaseInterface<A>
{
   public A() { }

   public async Task<List<A>> Handler(List<A> items)
   {
      var newList= new List<A>();
      foreach (var item in items)
      {
          newList.Add(new A
          {
              ID = item.ID,
              Name = item.Status,
              Retrieved = DateTime,
          });
      }
    // ...
    }
}
```

or totally if you want make that `Handler` as a generic method you can do something like:

```
public interface IBaseInterface
{
  //common props
} 
public class DataType1 : IBaseInterface
{
    public DataType1() { }   
}
```

and

```
public class Common
{
    public async Task<List<T>> Handler<T>(List<T> items) where T : IBaseInterface
    {
        var newList = new List<T>();
        ....
    }
}
```

and call it like(just for example) :

```
public class Consumer
{
    public void Call()
    {
        var param1 = new List<DataType1>();
        var t = new Common().Handler<DataType1>(param1).Result;
    }
}
```